# Java implementations are not required to implement RELAX NG validation via SchemaFactory?

Tags: java, relaxng

**Background:**

I have a RELAX NG Schema and a few XML files that are supposed to follow the schema. I'm trying to validate the XML files to the Schema in Java and I'm getting an error:

> *No SchemaFactory that implements the schema language specified by: http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0 could be loaded*

I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321748/validating-an-xml-file-using-relax-ng-schema-in-java-ide-eclipse) with the same problem and one of the answers says,

> Java implementations are not required to implement RELAX NG validation
>   via SchemaFactory. So even if it works in one environment, it is not
>   portable...

**Question:**

Is it true that I cannot create a portable validator for RELAX NG without relying on things like [the Jing library](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/api/jing/com/thaiopensource/validate/ValidationDriver.html)?

I'm trying to avoid the use of external libraries in my application.

**Validation in Java:**

```
        ...

        DocumentBuilderFactory builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        builder.setNamespaceAware(true);
        SchemaFactory schfactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.RELAXNG_NS_URI);

        Schema schema = schfactory.newSchema(new File("Configuration/Schema.rng"));
        builder.setSchema(schema);
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();


        DocumentBuilder build = builder.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = build.parse(new File(filepath));
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

        validator.validate(source);

        ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is true. XML Schema as defined by the W3C is the only portable schema language, to my knowledge. RELAX NG introduces additional features beyond normal XML Schema.

Answer (score 0):

This [IBM Post](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/x-javaxmlvalidapi/index.html#listing2) clarified my question.

> Out of the box, the JDK doesn't include a RELAX NG validator.